# drawing map with paths and zooming function

Tags: android, canvas, path

I am drawing a map with predefined paths. The Map can be moved and can be zoomed in and out.
This worked great and quick and fluent and looked good when zooming in on my Android 4.0.4.

Since I got an Update to 4.1.2 everything is different:
When zooming in the shapes will get now pixeled ( unsharp as in the attached Picture ) and
moving the map is very jerking. I didn't change the code.

Surpricingly in the emulator (AVG) it also looks good when zooming (see screenshot below)

What I do is:
- I have a lot of Pathes in an area of about x=0-2000 and y=0-1500
- I draw only the pathes that are visible inbetween my screensize
- Zooming I do with canvas.scale(x,x) in the onDraw() method of my custom view
- moving the map is done by canvas.translate(x,y) in the onDraw() method of my custom view

What I tried:

- I tried to tranform all pathes with scaling insteed of using canvas.scale() -> This would work, but my Shapes get to large, so they can't be drawn : "Shape path too large to be rendered into a texture"
- recreate the pathes with large coordinates . Same problem and its very slow -> "Shape path too large to be rendered into a texture"
- To part the shapes in several shapes is not the solution, because it already worked before on my 4.0.4 and I also like to draw borders correctly. (coastlines for example)

[image]

Emulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
With my new JellyBean Update Hardware acceleration was defaulted to on and Hardwareacceleration seams to be buggy. I had to explicity false the "Hardware acceleration" in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <application
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

regards